# Two where in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A have query: "SELECT date, COUNT(id) FROM leads WHERE userkey = '$userkey' GROUP BY DAY(date)"

I want add second where is_lead 1

Example:

[FIRST]

`SELECT date, COUNT(id) FROM leads WHERE userkey = '$userkey' GROUP BY DAY(date)`

[SECOND]

`SELECT COUNT(price) from leads WHERE userkey = '$userkey' and is_lead = 1`

Union not work.

Please Help!

Comment: Can you post your EXACT code as it is written in the file.

Comment: And your question doesn't actually make sense. You want to add a second WHERE criteria, to which statement? Do you mean you want to select results when is_lead is equal to one value OR another value?

Comment: can you explain what is the exact result you need to get from the query?

Comment: The general syntax is correct as you show: SELECT.... WHERE a=b and c=d. When you say 'doesn't work' does that mean you get an error or no/unexpected results. Where is $userkey defined or passed from?

Comment: Why are you using `count(price)`?

Answer (score 2):

or you want to do this?

```
SELECT a.userkey,DATE, COUNT(id),b.countp 
  FROM leads a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(price) AS countp 
        FROM leads 
        WHERE userkey = '$userkey' AND is_lead = 1) b
    ON a.userkey=b.userkey
WHERE userkey = '$userkey' 
GROUP BY DAY(DATE)
```